# git clone over SSH in PowerShell with Yubikey on W10

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, yubico

On a new Windows 10 install (Build 18362) I would like to use my Yubikey Neo, which has an Authentication subkey (along with an Encryption and a Signing subkey), to clone a Git repo over SSH:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:boggin/something.git
```

I have a `gpg-agent.conf`:

```
enable-putty-support
enable-ssh-support
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
```

Note that OpenSSH, which is the default SSH client now, won't work ([Support GPG and smartcard users](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/827)) but you can use PuTTY. I've tried setting the `ssh.variant` to `putty` in my `.gitconfig` but this doesn't seem to work.

What steps do I need to take to make Git use PuTTY SSH and recognize the Yubikey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps have worked for my case.

In a [Yubikey + Windows](https://gist.github.com/PatrickLang/7be00ba46a43eca3ef64ffe64b494749#authenticating-to-github) guide I found:

```
git config --global core.sshcommand 'plink -agent'
```

The console will hang if you try to clone a repo now but the above linked guide shows how you can get past this:

```
putty.exe -ssh git@github.com
```

Now `git clone` will work.

Comment: A little addendum. If you have a local SSH key in .ssh that you need to use then you are best commenting out sshcommand, opening a new PS session and then using git. This changes from using Putty to OpenSSH.